# Encrypt user_name in jwt token

Tags: spring-security, jwt, token

how can I encrypt or obfuscate user_name in JWT token? We failed a penetration test because it.

[username in jwt token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVw4w.png)

Answer (score -1):

These are some recommendations to help you pass the penetration testing :

- as the UserID is shown in the Token , the attacker can't change it as the Token has it's own signature .
- Use the User ID from the database instead of the username.

if the only option is to encrypt the User ID , then you can get the username encrypted/decrypted by a filter in the backend server .